# Streaming games from PC to RP

Tags: networking, linux

Let's say I want to play Supertux on big TV screen with RP connected. I don't want, and it's not always possible, to install all PC games on RP. What's the best way to run games on PC and display them on RP? I tried SSH X forwarding and tightvnc and it both cases Supertux was just playable but nothing more because lag was clear. I was thinking about giving freenx a try but I would like to know your opinions. I run Linux on my PC.

EDIT: I am going to get an extra keyboard to connect to RP or use Synergy and use my PC keyboard to play games

Answer (score 1):

You are already doing the 'best way'.
There isn't really a best way to play games over a remote desktop. You are going to get noticible latency regardless of which software you use.

Splashtop would probably be the one that could get the closest, but there's no client for Linux, much less an ARM based linux distro. Plus you also need a nVidia graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are doing the only reasonable way I can think of.

The problem is latency.  The computer you are running the VNC server on is already using a lot of resources to run the game, compounding the issue.  Unless you write some very specialized software (or port the game), you are going to get a lot of lag with transmitting a game to your Raspberry Pi.